# Local Editor is not auto refreshing remote files when opened from winSCP

Tags: remote-access, sftp, winscp

I am using WinSCP to access a remote directory on ubuntu 18.04 from windows10.

I started an SFTP session and opened a remote file from winscp file browser, say `hello.txt`, on a local editor Geany.

1. I make some changes in `hello.txt` remotely.
2. winscp updates the timestamp of `hello.txt` on my local system.
3. Geany does not pick up the change in `hello.txt` when I refresh/reload the file using CTRL+R.
4. Changes in `hello.txt` are taken in only after I close Geany completely and reopen hello.txt from winscp file browser.

Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Comment: After you save the file in the editor, and you reload the directory in WinSCP file panel, does the file timestamp and size change?

Comment: Yes it does @MartinPrikryl

Comment: So WinSCP does upload the changed file, right? It's some other software that does not pick up the change.

Comment: Yes correct. Infact no editor on my system is picking up the changed file.

Comment: What is *"editor on my system"*? Local system or remote system? What editor?

Comment: "editor on my system" means local system editor.
My local system is windows 10 and remote is ubuntu18.04.
I tried Geany and Notepad ++.

Comment: I'm lost. How can a local editor pickup the changed file on a remote system? Please edit your question with more detailed explanation of you workflow.

Comment: Edited the question.
Let me know if the problem is clear to you now.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading file panel only (Ctrl+R) does not make WinSCP re-download the edited files.

After the reload, you need to use "Edit" to force the re-download of the file. If your editor is able to detect the file change, it should reload the file. Notepad++ does. I do not know Geany.

Comment: Correct both Notepad++ and Geany has the capability to detect the file change automatically and it works pretty well apart from when winscp is changing the file.

In this case, neither of them is not auto-detecting the change, I tried both the editors.

Comment: For me it works with Notepad++. I reload the directory with `Ctrl+R`. Then I "edit" the already opened file again with `F4`. Notepad++ prompts me with *"This file has been modified by another program. Do you want to reload it?"*. After selecting *Yes*, I see the new contents in the editor.